# Dataframe.rdd.count throws No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters when using case class with List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark 2.1.0 and also checked this scenario on 2.1.1.
This is very weird to me, and it seems like a Serialization problem.
I am using case class that contains a scala List and I am hitting the following error:

```
Executor task launch worker for task 1] [CodeGenerator.logError]: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 111, Column 64: No applicable constructor/method found for actual parameters "scala.collection.Seq"; candidates are: "com.minute.playground.WithList(scala.collection.immutable.List)"
```

/* 001 */

I created a short example code that present the problem

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
case class Simple(str: String)
case class WithList(list : List[String])
object RddCountFailOnCaseClassWithList {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("WhyLikeThis").master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._    
    val df1: Dataset[Simple] = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[Simple](List(new Simple("1"))).as[Simple]
    df1.show()
    println(df1.rdd.count())

    val df2: Dataset[WithList] = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[WithList](List(new WithList(List("1")))).as[WithList]
    df2.show()
    //This will fail !!! ? But why ?
    println(df2.rdd.count())
  }
}
```

What am i doing wrong ? 
Am I not supposed to use List inside my model ?

Comment: I got the same error, but because I define an implicit encoder for my case class, try import spark.implicits._ seem to solve my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bug :)
You did nothing wrong. Looks like `List` somewhere converted to `Seq` and code generator can't find required constructor.
Your code works with spark 2.2.0 though, so it got fixed.

If you want to use spark 2.1.0 you can try to change your implementation to

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}

case class Simple(str: String)

case class WithSeq(list: Seq[String])

object RddCountFailOnCaseClassWithList {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("WhyLikeThis").master("local[2]").enableHiveSupport.getOrCreate
    import spark.implicits._
    val df1: Dataset[Simple] = {
      spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[Simple](List(Simple("1"))).as[Simple]
    }
    df1.show()
    println(df1.rdd.count())

    val df2: Dataset[WithSeq] = spark.sqlContext.createDataFrame[WithSeq](List(WithSeq(List("1")))).as[WithSeq]
    df2.show()
    //hooray, it works! :)
    println(df2.rdd.count())
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

case class WithList(list : **Seq**[String])

List is scala.collection.**immutable**.List

**Seq** is scala.collection.Seq